# How do I pass an ngrx actionCreator as a function parameter?

Tags: ngrx-store, typescript-generics

How can I type the `action` parameter of the `loader` function so that it does not use `TypedAction`, which is not exported by ngrx?

I want to ensure type safety as the current example does.

```
const loadItemsAction = createAction(
  'load items',
  props<{ items: Item[] }>()
);

function loader(action: ActionCreator<
  string,
  (props: {
    items: Item[];
  }) => TypedAction<string> & { items: Item[] }   // TypedAction is not exported from ngrx!
>){
  return action({ items: [{name: 'item1'}, { name: 'item2'}]});
}
```

I can effectively destructure TypedAction as follows, but it loses the indication that an Action is being returned. Is there a better way?

```
function loader(action: ActionCreator<
  string,
  (props: {
    items: Item[];
  }) => { readonly type: string, items: Item[] }
>){
  return action({ items: [{name: 'item1'}, { name: 'item2'}]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get anywhere with the existing ngrx types so added my own interface which identifies the object as an ActionCreator and allows easy specification of the type of those objects:

```
export interface ActionCreatorWithProps<TPropArgs extends object = {}>
  extends ActionCreator<
    string,
    (props: TPropArgs) => TPropArgs & { readonly type: string }
  > {}
```

used in original example:

```
function loader(action: ActionCreatorWithProps<{ items: Item[] }>) {
  return action({ items: [{name: 'item1'}, { name: 'item2'}]});
}
```